# How to fit mixture of gaussian with custom made function?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am familar with MATLAB and used to do mixed distribution fitting with my own function. I wanted to learn the same thing with python but struggling to do. I am not sure how to define the parameter constants and get the value of fitted parameters i.e. mu1,sigma1, mu2, sigma2 and probability.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np


class gaussian_mixture(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self,x):
        disA=np.exp(-0.5*(x-mu1)**2 / s1**2.) / (s1*np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi))
        disB=np.exp(-0.5*(x-mu2)**2 / s2**2.) / (s2*np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi))
        return p1*disA+(1-p)*disB


mu=6
sigma=2
data1=mu+sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
mu=1
sigma=1
data2=mu+sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
data=np.hstack((data1,data2))
print(data2.shape,data.shape)
height,xrange,patches=plt.hist(data,bins=50,density=True,facecolor='g',alpha=0.75)
gaussian = gaussian_mixture(name='gaussianmix')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works for me.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def bimodal(x,mu1,mu2,s1,s2,p1):
    disA=np.exp(-0.5*(x-mu1)**2 / s1**2.) / (s1*np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi))
    disB=np.exp(-0.5*(x-mu2)**2 / s2**2.) / (s2*np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi))
    return p1*disA+(1-p1)*disB

mu=6
sigma=2
data1=mu+sigma*np.random.randn(10000,1)

mu=1
sigma=1
data2=mu+sigma*np.random.randn(10000,1)

data=np.vstack((data1,data2))
print(data2.shape,data.shape)

hist=plt.hist(data,bins=30,density=True,facecolor='g',alpha=0.75)
x = [hist[0], 0.5*(hist[1][1:]+hist[1][:-1])]
xdata=x[1]
ydata=x[0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(bimodal, xdata, ydata)
print('point',popt)
plt.plot(xdata, bimodal(xdata, *popt), 'k-', label='fit: mu1=%5.3f, 
   mu2=%5.3f, s1=%5.3f,s2=%5.3f,p=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]